# How to show google map using address in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I am showing google map in my app using Google Maps iOS API. I am able to show a map by giving the `longitude` & `latitude` of the place.I am using following code to show the google map.

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;
```

Now i want to show the map for the custom address.Please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Refer this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: Post your link as answer i would accept it@SweetAngel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer below link, implement in your code and try it. It may help to solve your problem.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "Reverse GeoCoding".

> The term geocoding generally refers to translating a human-readable address into a location on a map. The process of doing the opposite, translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is known as reverse geocoding.

All you need to do is send lat and long and get the readable address.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=API_KEY
```

for more info on "Reverse geo coding" read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding).